# How to load more items in a ListView using AsyncTask or any other method

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am very new to android development and I know that this question might be answer before but I can't seem to find a suitable answer for my situation. I am creating an android app which have a `ListView` to show list of items. I need to show more items (like 10 more items) when the user reaches the footer of the `ListView`. I have implemented the `setOnScrollListener()`. My only issue and for which I need your guidance is that how can I get more items when the user reaches the bottom of the `ListView`. Should I create another `AsyncTask` for it? If yes then how can I ahieve this ... I am currently showing 10 items and I am getting those items through an API in `JSON` format using an `AsyncTask`. Below is the code for that `AsyncTask`.

```
public class GetRecipeData extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {
        public final int NUMBER_OF_POSTS = 10;

        int responseCode = -1;
        JSONObject recipeJsonResponse = null;

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {


            try {
                URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://www.bestfoodrecipesever.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug="+RECIPE_CAT+"&count="+NUMBER_OF_POSTS);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) blogFeedUrl.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();

                responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    if (inputStream == null) {
                        // Nothing to do.
                        return null;
                    }
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                        // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                        // buffer for debugging.
                        buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                        // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                        return null;
                    }
                    String recipeDataJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                    recipeJsonResponse = new JSONObject(recipeDataJsonStr);

                }else {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Unsuccessful HTTP Response Code: " + responseCode);
                }
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IO Exception Caught: ",e);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
            }
            return recipeJsonResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mRecipeData = result;
            handleRecipeData();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the `handleRecipeData()` Method:

```
private void handleRecipeData() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(mRecipeData == null){
            handleErrors();

        }else {
            try {
                getRecipeData();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
            }
        }
    }
```

And Here is the code for the `getRecipeData()` Method which is being used within the `handleRecipeData()` Method:

```
private void getRecipeData() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonPosts = mRecipeData.getJSONArray("posts");
        mRecipePostData = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
            title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
            String author = post.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR).getString("name");
            author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
            String imgUrl = post.getJSONObject(KEY_IMG_URL).getJSONObject("full").getString("url");
            String recipeContent = post.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
            recipeContent = Html.fromHtml(recipeContent).toString();
            String recipeUrl = post.getString(KEY_RECIPE_URL);

            HashMap<String, String> singleRecipePost = new HashMap<>();
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_IMG_URL, imgUrl);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_CONTENT, recipeContent);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_RECIPE_URL, recipeUrl);

            mRecipePostData.add(singleRecipePost);
        }

        String[] keys = {KEY_TITLE};
        int[] ids = {R.id.list_recipe_title};

        mRecipeAdapter = new ExtendedSimpleAdapter(getContext(), mRecipePostData, R.layout.itemlistrow, keys, ids);
        listView.setAdapter(mRecipeAdapter);
        mRecipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I am really stuck with this issue ... Can somebody help me out with this ... I would be greatful to you.

I also created a custom Adapter ExtendedSimpleAdapter. Here is the code for this Adapter. In case someone might want to review it:

```
public class ExtendedSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    Context context2;

    public ExtendedSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to){
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        context2=context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Then we get reference for Picasso
        //TextView recipeTitle = (TextView) v.getTag();
        ImageView recipeThumb = (ImageView) v.getTag();
        if(recipeThumb == null){
            //recipeTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_recipe_title);
            recipeThumb = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_recipe_thumb);
            //v.setTag(recipeTitle);
            v.setTag(recipeThumb); // <<< THIS LINE !!!!
        }
            // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
            String TAG_IMAGE = "thumbnail_images";
            String url = ((Map<String,String>) getItem(position)).get(TAG_IMAGE);

        // do Picasso
        // maybe you could do that by using many ways to start

        Picasso.with(context2).load(url).resize(300, 200).centerCrop().into(recipeThumb);

        // return the view

        return v;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to call your async task again and when response comes you need to add in the same list you have supplied to adapter and need to call notifydatasetchange on adapter object. you can use third party list as well, https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews

Comment: I tried to call my current AsyncTask but it shows the same results as before in the listview

Comment: already doing it `mRecipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` might be doing wrong ?

Comment: please check are you getting new data from the api, lets suppose in my api i have page_limit, so on scroll i will pass page_limit=10 so api return 10th page data. so you need to check with you api as well that is it returning same data or different data.

Comment: API is showing 10 recent items ... I mean newly added items are on top .. so at first the api will show the latest items .. and if I add a new item then the last item (the 10th item will disappear) do you think this might be because of the API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set adapter every time it will show you new data all the time when you will call for data. Just set it first time then only notify the adapter when you received new data from JSON.

Or you can use another List to store new data and add this list to your main List -

```
 yourMainList.addAll(anotherList);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**UPDATES--**

**1-** Take a boolean value to check list is scrolling or not **boolean iScrolling = false** and make it **true** inside **onScroll()**-

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0) {
                    isScrolling = true;
                    mFooter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    /*GetRecipeData getRecipeData = new GetRecipeData();
                    getRecipeData.execute();*/
                    GetRecipeData getRecipeData = new GetRecipeData();
                    getRecipeData.execute(yourCounts); // update
                }
            }
        });
```

Now some changes inside **getRecipeData()**-

```
 private void getRecipeData() throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonPosts = mRecipeData.getJSONArray("posts");
    mRecipePostData = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
        JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
        String title = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
        title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
        String author = post.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR).getString("name");
        author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
        String imgUrl = post.getJSONObject(KEY_IMG_URL).getJSONObject("full").getString("url");
        String recipeContent = post.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
        recipeContent = Html.fromHtml(recipeContent).toString();
        String recipeUrl = post.getString(KEY_RECIPE_URL);

        HashMap<String, String> singleRecipePost = new HashMap<>();
        singleRecipePost.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        singleRecipePost.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
        singleRecipePost.put(KEY_IMG_URL, imgUrl);
        singleRecipePost.put(KEY_CONTENT, recipeContent);
        singleRecipePost.put(KEY_RECIPE_URL, recipeUrl);

        mRecipePostData.add(singleRecipePost);
    }

    String[] keys = {KEY_TITLE};
    int[] ids = {R.id.list_recipe_title};

    if (!isScrolling){
        mRecipeAdapter = new ExtendedSimpleAdapter(getContext(), mRecipePostData, R.layout.itemlistrow, keys, ids);
        listView.setAdapter(mRecipeAdapter);
        mRecipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }else{
        mRecipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        isScrolling = false;
    }
}
```

**2-** Or you can do it with the help of another **List**-
Take another List and add data on it and add this List to your main List, inside **getRecipeData()**-

```
 private void getRecipeData() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonPosts = mRecipeData.getJSONArray("posts");
        if (!isScrolling) {
            mRecipePostData = new ArrayList<>();
        }else{
            yourSecondList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
            title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
            String author = post.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR).getString("name");
            author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
            String imgUrl = post.getJSONObject(KEY_IMG_URL).getJSONObject("full").getString("url");
            String recipeContent = post.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
            recipeContent = Html.fromHtml(recipeContent).toString();
            String recipeUrl = post.getString(KEY_RECIPE_URL);

            HashMap<String, String> singleRecipePost = new HashMap<>();
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_IMG_URL, imgUrl);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_CONTENT, recipeContent);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_RECIPE_URL, recipeUrl);

            if (!isScrolling) {
                mRecipePostData.add(singleRecipePost);
            }else{
                yourSecondList.add(singleRecipePost);
            }

        }

        String[] keys = {KEY_TITLE};
        int[] ids = {R.id.list_recipe_title};

        if (!isScrolling){
            mRecipeAdapter = new ExtendedSimpleAdapter(getContext(), mRecipePostData, R.layout.itemlistrow, keys, ids);
            listView.setAdapter(mRecipeAdapter);
            mRecipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{
            mRecipePostData.addAll(yourSecondList);
            mRecipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            isScrolling = false;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATES-**

Change your AsyncTask params-

```
 public class GetRecipeData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    // your code..

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://www.bestfoodrecipesever.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=" + RECIPE_CAT + "&count=" + params[0]);

            // your code...
        }
    }
}
```

And also make some change here-

```
 if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        GetRecipeData getRecipeData = new GetRecipeData();
        getRecipeData.execute(yourCount);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),getString(R.string.no_network), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: can you guide me how can I do this ?? Are you saying that I should create another list view and on the onScroll event I add that second listview to the first listview ?

Comment: Thanks Deepanshu ... let me try this and get back to you

Comment: tried but somehow it didn't work .... do you think that this could be the issue `http://www.bestfoodrecipesever.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=alltimetoprecipes&count=10` because I am just getting 10 recent results from the API

Comment: when I scroll down to the last item the on scroll triggers but no new Items were loaded ... only the recent 10 were visible ... I think there is a issue with the api ...

Comment: I used the 2nd method .... but when I scroll to the last item the function initiate and shows that something is happening and but it loads the same items ... and when i tap on a item to view the details and then go back to the listview my application crashes ... here is the logcat logs ... http://pastebin.com/A9DXfWtn

Comment: You get crashes because of the fragment lifecycle issues that sometimes causes getActivity() to be null. Use this- Context context; and context = getActivity(); now replace getActivity() with context.

Comment: Thanks ... will try this ... but still figuring out the loading more items issue ... do you think that my api could be the problem ?

Comment: try to change count in second time.

Comment: Increasing the page count by 10 ?

Comment: will it be like `NUMBER_OF_POSTS += 10` and should place it in `getRecipeData.execute(NUMBER_OF_POSTS += 10)` I am really sorry for being so annoying because I am really new to android and this is my first project.

Comment: so the value of param[0] will be the value of NUMBER_Of_POSTS .. right and where do i increment this value ?

Comment: So in the OnScroll function I will run `getRecipeData.execute(NUMBER_OF_POSTS += 10)`

Comment: have a look at this updated code .... does it seems correct to you ? http://pastebin.com/4cj3VDLX

Comment: if you like i can send you the apk for you to test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107846/discussion-between-deepanshu-harbola-and-faisalblink).

Comment: Thanks Deepanshu ... you have gone an extra mile to provide me with a solution thanks alot ...

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
 //used for populate the listView
 private void populateListView(HashMap<String, String> datas){
    if(mRecipeAdapter ==null){
       String[] keys = {KEY_TITLE};
       int[] ids = {R.id.list_recipe_title};
       mRecipeAdapter = new ExtendedSimpleAdapter(getContext(), datas, R.layout.itemlistrow, keys, ids);
       listView.setAdapter(mRecipeAdapter);
    }else
    {
      mRecipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 }
//create ListView Data::: i have removed your five last line, and repleced them by return mRecipePostData 
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getRecipeData() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonPosts = mRecipeData.getJSONArray("posts");
        mRecipePostData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
            title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
            String author = post.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR).getString("name");
            author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
            String imgUrl = post.getJSONObject(KEY_IMG_URL).getJSONObject("full").getString("url");
            String recipeContent = post.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
            recipeContent = Html.fromHtml(recipeContent).toString();
            String recipeUrl = post.getString(KEY_RECIPE_URL);

            HashMap<String, String> singleRecipePost = new HashMap<>();
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_AUTHOR, author);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_IMG_URL, imgUrl);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_CONTENT, recipeContent);
            singleRecipePost.put(KEY_RECIPE_URL, recipeUrl);

            mRecipePostData.add(singleRecipePost);
        }
       return mRecipePostData;
    } 

//after getData, i am populating ListView
private void handleRecipeData() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(mRecipeData == null){
            handleErrors();

        }else {
            try {
                HashMap<String, String> datas=getRecipeData();
                populateListView(datas);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception Caught: ",e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I will adjust my code and let you know it if worked or not

Comment: Tried your code ... but some how the AsyncTask is not running in the `setOnScrollListener()` method ... any idea what could be the issue ... data is loading fine for the first time ...

Comment: ok, some where, i can see this URL:
"http://www.bestfoodrecipesever.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug="+RECIPE_CAT+"&count="+NUMBER_OF_POSTS
are you sure that you change the RECIPE_CAT? it seem to be the page number and you take 10 lines=NUMBER_OF_POSTS

Comment: i thing that you have to increase  RECIPE_CAT at each populateListView in order to switch to the next recip_post_page. also, to perform what you what to do, the line  mRecipePostData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); should be remove to getRecipeData() and set on another part of your code, (inside constructor for example)

Comment: RECIPE_CAT is a constant for the category name ... This is the category of which we are getting the recipes ... NUMBER_OF_POSTS is the count of posts to retrieve .... Why would I need to increase RECIPE_CAT .. it is only the name of the category ... Do i need to increase the NUMBER_OF_POSTS ? ... I will check your pastebin and let you know

Comment: instead of this `RECIPE_CAT++;` shouldn't we use `NUMBER_OF_POSTS++`

Comment: huuun, i am understanding more and more your idéa.
NUMBER_OF_POSTS++ yes it is possible [buuut, it is not prety..:-).]
if you want to use this way, dont considère my last post and just increment NUMBER_OF_POSTS at each "populateListView"  (NUMBER_OF_POST++) so let mRecipePostData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>() where it was préviously.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ... I tired the code in the pasetbin you sent me ... but it didn't work ... I don't think that the increment would work here ..

Comment: Do you think it is something wrong with the API ... this is the url from which I getting the data `http://www.bestfoodrecipesever.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=easybutimpressive&count=10`

Comment: your api give me that response: {"status":"error","error":"Not found."}

Comment: Oh sorry there were no posts in that category ... please check this ... and I am really sorry for the late replying .... `http://www.bestfoodrecipesever.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=americancuisines&count=10`

Comment: I am really having a hard time getting this done ... I am not sure what is it that I am doing wrong or what approach should I take to make it work ...

Comment: the second link that I have sent is working but when I copy the from here (stackoverflow) and paste it in the browser it doesn't work ... strange

Comment: nope not working if I copy it from the pastebin as well .. can you type out the link .. just the part after `?slug=`