# How to infinite scroll load more with Recycleview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

### How to infinite scroll load more with Recycleview

*how can i display result like infinite means when user scroll dynamic data automatically fetch and show. so loading time consume and application will work fine.*

File Name: **MainActivity.java**       //Main Java file that i want to show load more

```
        package com.ejobbox.ejobbox;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.text.format.DateFormat;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import retrofit2.Call;
        import retrofit2.Callback;
        import retrofit2.Response;
        import retrofit2.Retrofit;
        import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            private RecyclerView recyclerView;
            private ProgressBar progressBar;
            private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
            private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
            private ArrayList<Model> list;
            private String baseURL="http://mywebsite.com/";
            public static List<WPPost> mListPost;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

                mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

                list=new ArrayList<Model>();
                // call retrofit

                getRetrofit();

                adapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(list,MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            private void getRetrofit(){
                Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(baseURL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
               Call<List<WPPost>> call= service.getPostInfo();
               call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPost>>() {

                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Response<List<WPPost>> response) {
                       Log.e("mainactivty","response"+ response.body());
                       progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                       for(int i=0; i<response.body().size();i++){

                           Log.e ("main","Title"+ response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered()+"  "+
                                        response.body().get(i).getId());

                           String tempdetails=response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered().toString();
                           tempdetails=tempdetails.replace("<p>","");
                           tempdetails=tempdetails.replace("</p>","");
                           String linkdetail=response.body().get(i).getLink().toString();

                           String date=response.body().get(i).getDate().toString();

                           list.add(new Model(Model.IMAGE_TYPE, response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                                   tempdetails,date,
                                   response.body().get(i).getLinks().getWpFeaturedmedia().get(0).getHref(),linkdetail) );
                       }
                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Throwable t) {

                   }
               });
            }
        }
```

(*This is RecyclearViewAdapter that i have define recyclear view Adapter.*)
 
File Name: ***RecyclearViewAdapter.java***  //Recyclear View Adapter File

```
    package com.ejobbox.ejobbox;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
        private ArrayList<Model> dataset;
        private Context mContext;

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Model> mlist, Context context) {
          this.dataset=mlist;
          this.mContext=context;
        }

        public static class ImageTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView title,subtitle,link,date;
            ImageView imageView;

            public ImageTypeViewHolder(View itemView){
                super(itemView);
                this.title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                this.link=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.link);
                this.subtitle=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
                this.imageView=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                this.date=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.postdetails,parent,false);
            return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final Model object=dataset.get(position);


            ((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setText(object.title);
            ((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setText(object.subtitle);
            //((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).link.setText(object.link);
            ((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).date.setText((CharSequence) object.date);

            ((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, WPPostDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("itemPosition",position);

                    intent.putExtra("link",object.link.toString());
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() { return dataset.size();}
    }
```

Comment: Do not use infinite scroll it does not work as expected.

You can use this

            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {


                if (isLastItemDisplaying())
                {
                    scrollCount=scrollCount+10;
                    L.v("scroll count",""+recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
                    loadMoreItems(scrollCount);

                }

                }
            });

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Answer (score 1):

Do not use infinite scroll it does not work as expected.

You can use this

```
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {


            if (isLastItemDisplaying())
            {
                scrollCount=scrollCount+10;
                L.v("scroll count",""+recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
                loadMoreItems(scrollCount);

            }

            }
        });

private boolean isLastItemDisplaying()
{
    if (storiesList.getAdapter().getItemCount()!=0) {
        int last_visible_count=manager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        if (last_visible_count!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && last_visible_count==storiesList.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Inside this loadMoreItems method call your api. Make sure to send this scroll count to your server on each api call .And in sql query you have to do this

EX: 
For example on first time your count is 0;
SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 0,10

On Scroll your scrollCount value will get increased by 10 (you can use your value scroll count values will fetch next 10 rows)

SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 10,10

Answer (score 1):

You only have to add your new data to the last position of list movies and everything will work fine. For this-

Create a new List of **List<Model> newList** and add your updated data to it. Now add **newList** into **list** and notify to adapter. Just like below-

```
  List<Model> newList = new ArrayList<>();

  // your code..

  recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            loadingMore=true;
            getRetrofit();

            int currentSize = adapter.getItemCount();
            list.addAll(newList);
            adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(currentSize, list.size() - 2);
        }
    });
```

And here you can find the **[EndlessScrollListener](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView)** class.

please look at my other related answers to more details-

[How to load more items in a ListView using AsyncTask or any other method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156873/how-to-load-more-items-in-a-listview-using-asynctask-or-any-other-method/36157919#36157919)

[Continious scrolling in recyclerview by Json request and adding new item with previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816701/continious-scrolling-in-recyclerview-by-json-request-and-adding-new-item-with-pr/36077920#36077920)

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for Simple Implementation of **Endless Scrolling RecyclerView** using a Simple Library compiled from the various sources.

Add this line in `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.hereshem.lib:awesomelib:2.0.1'
```

Create RecyclerView Layout in Activity with

```
<com.hereshem.lib.recycler.MyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Create a ViewHolder by passing the class that supports

```
public static class EVHolder extends MyViewHolder<Events> {
    TextView date, title, summary;
    public EVHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        date = v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        title = v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        summary = v.findViewById(R.id.summary);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(Events c) {
        date.setText(c.date);
        title.setText(c.title);
        summary.setText(c.summary);
    }
}
```

Create Items List variable and adapters with very few lines by passing items, class and layout in the adapter

```
List<Events> items = new ArrayList<>();
MyRecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, items, EVHolder.class, R.layout.row_event);
recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ClickListener and LoadMore Listener can be added with following lines

```
recycler.setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recycler Item Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

recycler.setOnLoadMoreListener(new MyRecyclerView.OnLoadMoreListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore() {
        loadData();
    }
});
loadData();
```

After the data is loaded this must be called

```
recycler.loadComplete();
```

When no LoadMore is required LoadMore layout can be hidden by calling

```
recycler.hideLoadMore();
```

More example can be found [here](https://github.com/hereshem/RecyclerViewWithLoadMoreAndServerRequest)

Hope this helps :)